# Filtering out string in a Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have the following formulas that I use to compute data in my Dataframe. The Datframe consists of data downloaded. My Index is made of dates, and the first row contains only strings..

```
cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
weight = 
pd.DataFrame([df[col] / df.sum(axis=1) for col in df], index=cols).T
std = pd.DataFrame([df.std(axis=1) for col in df], index=cols).T


                       A      B      C       D      E
2006-04-27 00:00:00   'dd'  'de'   'ede'   'wew'  'were'                     
2006-04-28 00:00:00  69.62  69.62  6.518   65.09  69.62
2006-05-01 00:00:00   71.5   71.5  6.522   65.16   71.5
2006-05-02 00:00:00  72.34  72.34  6.669   66.55  72.34
2006-05-03 00:00:00  70.22  70.22  6.662   66.46  70.22
2006-05-04 00:00:00  68.32  68.32  6.758   67.48  68.32
2006-05-05 00:00:00     68     68  6.805   67.99     68
2006-05-08 00:00:00  67.88  67.88  6.768   67.56  67.88
```

The Issue I am having is that the formulas I use do not seem to ignore the Index and also the first Indexed row where it's only 'strings'. Thus i get the following error for the weight formula:

> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'

and I get the following error for the std formula:

> ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the rows so as to compute weight and standard deviation as follows:

```
df_string = df.iloc[0]                       # Assign First row to DF
df_numeric = df.iloc[1:].astype(float)       # Assign All rows after first row to DF

cols = df_numeric.columns.values.tolist()
```

Computing:

```
weight = pd.DataFrame([df_numeric[col] / df_numeric.sum(axis=1) for col in df_numeric],    
                       index=cols).T
weight
```

[image]

```
std = pd.DataFrame([df_numeric.std(axis=1) for col in df_numeric],index=cols).T
std
```

[image]

To reassign, say `std` values back to the original `DF`, you could do:

```
df_string_std = df_string.to_frame().T.append(std)  
df_string_std
```

[image]

---

As the OP had difficulty in reproducing the results, here is the complete summary of the `DF` used:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 8 entries, 2006-04-27 to 2006-05-08
Data columns (total 5 columns):
A    8 non-null object
B    8 non-null object
C    8 non-null object
D    8 non-null object
E    8 non-null object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 384.0+ bytes

df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2006-04-27', '2006-04-28', '2006-05-01', '2006-05-02',
               '2006-05-03', '2006-05-04', '2006-05-05', '2006-05-08'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Starting `DF`used:

```
df
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!! however, i still get this error:TypeError:                      Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'  Somehow the Index is still showing in the calculations for the weight formula.. And that one also:ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> for the std formula

Comment: Isn't the `datetime` column the index? If not, you need to do: `df.set_index('Index', inplace=True)` as a prior step where 'Index' is the column containing dates.

Comment: thanks yes it is the Index, that's why I dont understand why i get that error..and still does after applying your suggestion

Comment: Alright.. So what are `df.index` and `df.columns` respectively and also their types? Looks like you have some strings interspersed with your otherwise datetime index.

Comment: I get this   dtype: object for the index type and column type i get that:
 
datetime64[ns] . i used: df.index.dtype and df. columns.dtype

Comment: That doesn't ring anything to my mind right now.  The types which you've provided should be vice-versa for it to work. What about `df.info()` and `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Yes it should be reversed, I get this for df.info and df.dtypes               datetime64[ns]  and
object       - maybe can i .copy() the dataframe and somehow reset the types?

Comment: I'm afraid I can only help this much. You haven't provided me the complete details to look into. Just in case you want to produce my results, I shall edit my post along their `dtypes` listed.

Comment: i can send you the python script if you dlike

Comment: I've edited the post with enough details. Try to match your dataframe to the above provided. You'll soon figure it out by yourself :-)